# Someone used solr5.5? In which directory should I put Mysql package?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, solr

My mysql-data-input.xml looks like:

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname" user="db_username" password="db_password"/>
```

obviously, it need mysql jar, but I don't know in which directory should I put mysql.jar.
The solr config directory is `/aparts/solr-5.5.0/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf`, also `mysql-data-input.xml` is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you can put the dependencies files/Jars any where. As long as you make sure in solrconfig.xml, you added the dependencies to the `lib` tag so Solr knows where it is.

Here is the [solrconfig.xml](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf/solrconfig.xml#L61) from techproducts which is one of the built in example project.

Here is a screenshot where I dump mysql connector into the dist folder of solr home and how my solrconfig looks like:

[image]

Comment: i  put it in war application, WEB-INF

Answer (score 0):

It should be added in the application server's lib folder.

I have been using apache-tomcat and added the same in tomcat's lib folder.

```
apache-tomcat-5.5.26/common/lib
```